# Do Struct-style register definitions consume RAM

Tags: c, avr, cmsis

So I've been scouring the internet for an answer and have not gotten anywhere.

What I want to know is if struct-style register definitions for microcontrollers (ARM mcu, AVR mcu) consume RAM. I know that if an object of a struct is instantiated it will consume RAM (either on the stack or otherwise).

But what about register definitions like the ones below, that are used by ARM in their CMSIS and similar to what the new ATTiny series use for their register definitions as far as I know.

Do these consume RAM memory specifically. I'm quite sure they would somewhat consume flash/program space, but RAM?

```
#define PORT              ((Port     *)0x41008000UL) /**< \brief (PORT) APB Base Address */
```

```
typedef struct {
       PortGroup                 Group[4];    /**< \brief Offset: 0x00 PortGroup groups [GROUPS] */
} Port;
```

```
typedef struct {
  __IO PORT_DIR_Type             DIR;         /**< \brief Offset: 0x00 (R/W 32) Data Direction */
  __IO PORT_DIRCLR_Type          DIRCLR;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x04 (R/W 32) Data Direction Clear */
  __IO PORT_DIRSET_Type          DIRSET;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x08 (R/W 32) Data Direction Set */
  __IO PORT_DIRTGL_Type          DIRTGL;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x0C (R/W 32) Data Direction Toggle */
  __IO PORT_OUT_Type             OUT;         /**< \brief Offset: 0x10 (R/W 32) Data Output Value */
  __IO PORT_OUTCLR_Type          OUTCLR;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x14 (R/W 32) Data Output Value Clear */
  __IO PORT_OUTSET_Type          OUTSET;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x18 (R/W 32) Data Output Value Set */
  __IO PORT_OUTTGL_Type          OUTTGL;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x1C (R/W 32) Data Output Value Toggle */
  __I  PORT_IN_Type              IN;          /**< \brief Offset: 0x20 (R/  32) Data Input Value */
  __IO PORT_CTRL_Type            CTRL;        /**< \brief Offset: 0x24 (R/W 32) Control */
  __O  PORT_WRCONFIG_Type        WRCONFIG;    /**< \brief Offset: 0x28 ( /W 32) Write Configuration */
  __IO PORT_EVCTRL_Type          EVCTRL;      /**< \brief Offset: 0x2C (R/W 32) Event Input Control */
  __IO PORT_PMUX_Type            PMUX[16];    /**< \brief Offset: 0x30 (R/W  8) Peripheral Multiplexing */
  __IO PORT_PINCFG_Type          PINCFG[32];  /**< \brief Offset: 0x40 (R/W  8) Pin Configuration */
       RoReg8                    Reserved1[0x20];
} PortGroup;
```

NOTE : All the code provided in the code blocks above are direct quotes from a user on EEVBlog. It is regarding register definitions provided in CMSIS. Link is [here](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/starting-with-stm32-cmsis/).

EDIT : I understand that MCUs have registers and accessing those registers don't consume RAM. But my confusion is in the **way** these registers are being referred to. For example :

```
// if a register address is 0x50

#define address 0x50    // This consumes no RAM as it is resolved during compilation

uint8_t addr = 0x50;    // This consumes RAM because it is now a variable


// So what about this??

typedef struct {
    uint8_t addr = 0x50;
} address_group;
```

So accessing the registers themselves won't use up RAM space, but the method we use to easily **refer** to those addresses, in this case using structs, is what I'm confused about.

All registers can be #define'd one by one which will consume no RAM, but the choice of doing it in struct format...?

Comment: No, they do not consume any RAM

Comment: They don't consume flash either.

Comment: No RAM required.

Comment: Wow, 3 people saying  they don't consume RAM. So are they all resolved during compilation? Or at the pre-processor stage?

Comment: Normally you define a pointer to that data type and assign the address of the memory mapped register block to the pointer. By dereferencing the pointer you can access the hardware register directly. That is what the first line does with `PORT` macro which even omits the pointer variable itself.

Comment: @Gerhardh I think I somewhat get it actually. So the trick is to do everything like normal C code (meaning things that would normally cost RAM) and then the line that changes everything is the #define that forces the preprocessor to resolve it first. Am I right in assuming that?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66045265/edit) your question to explain in written English how do you define RAM consumption, and provide some [mre] in your question. What about the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) ? **What *exact* cross-compiler are you using?** Some version of  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)? Which one? What compiler options?

Comment: Your hardware provides a number of registers. They are inside the CPU or some peripheral and can only be accessed via a memory address. There is no point in creating a copy of those registers in RAM. You just directly read or write from the memory address where the register is located. That `#define' only provides a name for that memory location.

Answer (score 3):

In order to control peripherals such as GPIO and UART, the peripherals provide registers that are mapped into the memory address space of the MCU.

The typical address range for such registers on STM32 MCUS is from 0x40000000 upwards. This is separate from both flash and RAM.

As an example: The baud rate register for USART1 might be at address 0x41006008. So by reading a word (32 bit) from that address, the baud rate can be read. And by writing to the address, it can be changed.

In C, it could look like:

```
*(volatile uint32_t*)0x41006008 = 115200;
```

However, it's much more readable and efficient if it looks like so:

```
USART1.BRR = 115200;
```

All the *defines* and *typedef*s shown in your question declare data types (such as `PortGroup`) and pseudo variables (such as `PORT`). I call them *pseudo* because they are not regular variables allocated in RAM but rather memory mapped structures built into hardware. (And data type declaration never consume memory anyway.)

The neat thing about this approach is: the code is easier to write and read and still the same size as the cryptic code. It's resolved at compile time as the compiler can figure out the absolute address of `USART1.BRR`.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, memory-mapped registers *are* RAM, in a way, though they can be updated by hardware and software both. They are located in the memory map at a location where the linker isn't allowed to mess around. The compiler in general has no awareness that the register area exists.

By using methods like those described here: [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290) , or by using a pre-made "register map" from the vendor, we tell the compiler to access an area of memory where it has no clue what's stored.

You can tell the compiler for example "there's a `PortGroup` struct at this location, from address `0x41008000UL` and beyond". The compiler then blindly trusts the programmer and accesses that area through the pointer provided, using the declared types of the struct. If these types matches the hardware registers, then everything will work just as if you had allocated variables there. But you actually don't need to have make the linker allocate memory in that area, because everything is already provided in the hardware.

Accessing the registers, or accessing any other form of variable for that matter, doesn't necessarily take any RAM. Given any random variable `int x;`, then `x` itself is allocated somewhere, but the act of *accessing* it with `x=0;` etc doesn't likely take any RAM.

---

And finally some misconceptions: `#define address 0x50` doesn't consume any RAM, not because it is resolved at compile-time, but because it consumes ROM instead. All numbers used by the program will be allocated somewhere in the executable.

If you have `uint8_t addr = 0x50;` ... `if(addr == something)`, the optimizing compiler does not necessarily have to allocate RAM space for `addr`. It could optimize away the whole variable. See this example for x86: https://godbolt.org/z/KroKhq. It didn't make any sense to allocate the variable so the compiler stored the magic number 0x50 (80 dec) in the machine code, as part of the `cmp` instruction. You will get identical machine code if you use `#define` in the same example.

Comment: `#define address 0x50` does NOT consume ROM. The *define* declaration itself doesn't generate any code or allocate anything. It only has an effect if it is used like `x.y  = address;` Then it will generate code (incl. constants).

Comment: @Codo Well I kind of assumed that it would be used in the program and trust the reader to have some common sense. Code doesn't consume any ROM if you don't download the program in the MCU either...

Comment: Typically a program includes header files with thousands of *define*s and will only use a few of them. It's important to understand if and when a *define* generates code.

Answer (score 0):

No, those structures don't take up RAM.  RAM is consumeed when you actually define a variable, with code like this

```c
unsigned int myInteger;  // takes RAM
struct foo myStruct;     // takes RAM
```

Lines like the ones above tell your compiler/linker to make symbols called `myInteger` and `myStruct` and allocate space for those symbols in the RAM area of your microcontroller (possibly on your stack).

On the other hand, when you define a struct type or make a `typedef`, that is different from defining a variable, and it doesn't take up any RAM:

```
struct foo {  // Does not take RAM, just defines a type.
  ...
};
```

When you define a pointer to a struct using the code below, you are just defining an expression that evaluates to a pointer to a struct that already exists in the hardware. You aren't doing anything that should consume RAM:

```c
// Does not take up RAM, just defines an expression.
#define PORTA ((struct GPIO *)0x1230)
```

When you *use* PORTA in your code, the lines of code that use it will take some code space.  Those lines might take some stack space when they execute, but they should not take up any RAM permanently.